# Attempting to perform PCA, plotting in PCA space

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pca

I have a dataset which I have read in and normalized called `normX`. I used the following block to set up PCA:

```
pca = PCA(n_components=None)

pca.fit_transform(normX)

pca.copy = True
pca.whiten = False
pca.iterated_power = 'auto'
pca.svd_solver = 'auto'
pca.random_state = None

# Calculate loading matrix
loadM = pca.components_.T * np.sqrt(pca.explained_variance_)

# Extracting loading vectors
loadV1 = loadM[:,0]
loadV2 = loadM[:,1]
loadV3 = loadM[:,2]
```

I am trying to now transform the original data into the principal component space and then plot the transformed data in `loadV1-loadV2`, `loadV1-loadV3` and `loadV2-loadV3` space so I can then discuss the results of the plot. My code for the first pace `loadV1-loadV2` is below, but it results in just a jumble of data on a single plot:

```
xvec= pca.components_[0]
yvec = pca.components_[1]

loadV1-loadV2 = np.dot(loadV1,loadV2)

xs = pca.transform(normX)[:,0]
ys = pca.transform(normX)[:,1]

for i in range(len(xvec)):
    plt.arrow(0, 0, xvec[i]*max(xs), yvec[i]*max(ys), color='r', width=0.0005, head_width=0.0025)
    plt.text(xvec[i]*max(xs)*1.2, yvec[i]*max(ys)*1.2, loadV1-loadV2, color='r')

for i in range(len(xs)):
    plt.plot(xs[i], ys[i], 'bo')
    plt.text(xs[i]*1.2, ys[i]*1.2, loadV1-loadV2, color='b')

plt.show()
```

This results in a plot with a lot of data jumbled close together and ends up having multiple vectors (red lines) plotted as points. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your second line `pca.fit_transform(normX)` *already* transforms the original data into principal component space, but you're not capturing the return value.

Comment: I see, I thought it was stored in the variable `pca`. Do I have to do `captured = pca.fit_transform(normX)`?

Comment: Yes, something like `transformed = pca.fit_transform(normX)` would do it. And the various hyperparameters (e.g, `whiten=False`) should be passed at `PCA` instantiation time: `pca = PCA(n_components=None, whiten=False)`. Assigning them *after* you've done the fit won't help very much.

Comment: Got it. As for plotting the `transformed` in `loadV1-loadV2` spaces and so on, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Would you be able to tell me where the plotting is incorrect?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure: it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve in the second half of the question.

Comment: @MarkDickinson In the second half, I'm trying to plot only the three first principal components in the PC space